# c++ - deterministic alternative to std::uniform_XXX_distribution with mt19937?

Tags: c++, random, distribution

I need a way to get deterministic sequences of ints and doubles.

```
template <class U>
constexpr auto get_random_value (std::mt19937 &gen, U min_value, U max_value)->U
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v <U, double> or std::is_same_v <U, float> ){
        std::uniform_real_distribution <U> distrib( min_value, max_value );
 
        return distrib( gen );
    }
    else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v <U, u32> or std::is_same_v <U, i32> ){
        std::uniform_int_distribution distrib( min_value, max_value );

        return distrib( gen );
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error( "error value type" );
    }
}
```

My issue is that one day to another, the same seeded value will lead to different results.
The distribution is to blame because it goes a long way to avoid the pitfall of the modulo.

But I need a precise way to always be certain that a sequence will always be the same starting from a given seed. And I need an unbiased partition (so % and rand() are out).

What kind of implementation will guarantee this?

Comment: All standard random engines like mersenne_twister_engine are deterministic.

Comment: Please give a minimal reproducible example? You haven’t shown where you’re doing the seeding, nor how this code is being invoked.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. But the distributions are not.

Comment: @NathanOliver Says who?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. MT itself is deterministic, but converting its outcomes to be unbiased on a restricted range involves an acceptance/rejection technique which means the number of calls to MT can vary for different range limits.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The standard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475773/why-does-stduniform-int-distribution-not-give-the-same-answer-across-different

Comment: AFAIK, the distribution may vary across different systems. But how could they vary on the same system (same machine, compiler and build options)?

Comment: @NathanOliver The standard says that it is implementation defined, not that it is non-deterministic.

Comment: any chance you are sharing the generator across multiple callers?

Comment: @SergeBallesta The standard requires identically-constructed distributions to be indistinguishable in behaviour. In my book this means they cannot vary within an implementation *in practice*. In theory you can have many weird things, like sizeof(int) being different on Fridays, but realistically common sense usually prevails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distributions in the C++ standard are not portable ("seed-stable"), in the sense that the result can change between [different implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42475773/3740047) (e.g. Microsoft STL vs gcc libstdc++ vs clang libc++) or even different versions (e.g. [Microsoft changed their implementation before](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/178)). The standard simply does not prescribe a specific algorithm, with the intention to allow implementations to [select the one with the best performance for each platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24554535/3740047).
So far, there is only a [proposal (D2059R0)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2059r0.pdf) to do something about this.
Note, however, that the generators are actually portable.

I have yet to see a library that **guarantees** portability.
However, in practice [boost.random](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) is known to produce reproducible result across platforms (see e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/e9mft4/when_did_you_want_to_use_random_but_couldnt/) or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7i21sn/til_uniform_int_distribution_is_not_portable/) or [here](https://blog.askesis.pl/post/2021/03/portable-random-number.html)). Also, Google's [abseil](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/random) library explicitly states that they do not provide a stability guarantee, but seems to produce the same result on different platforms nevertheless.
Here is a [live example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fEf4hbzGM) where you can see that to some extent (well, at least Linux vs Windows for a tiny selection of parameters).
The major point is not to update the libraries without checking for a breaking change. Also compare e.g. [this](https://blog.askesis.pl/post/2021/03/portable-random-number.html) blog post.
Or you could also implement a specific algorithm yourself (see e.g. [here](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html)) or simply copy the code from one the libraries to your code base and thereby effectively freezing its version.

For distributions involving floating point arithmetic, you also have the problem that the arithmetic itself is, generally speaking, far from stable across platforms since stuff like automatic vectorization (SSE2 vs AVX etc) or FPU settings might change behavior. See [this blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/) for more information. How far distributions, including the above mentioned libraries, are affected by this, I unfortunately do not know. The small example on godbolt mentioned above does at least not show any problem with `-ffast-math`, which is a good sign.

Whatever you do, I highly recommend to back up your choice by appropriate automatic tests (unit tests etc.) that catch any potential deviations in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer originates from a [related question that was eventually considered duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77680011/3492512), putting it here to complete the answers to the original question.)

## Reminder of some basic information

Recall that the [C++ standard offers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

- Three main Random Number Generators (RNGs):
  Generate sequences of (pseudo-)random numbers.

  - `std::linear_congruential_engine` (includes `std::minstd*`)
  - `std::mersenne_twister_engine` (includes `std::mt19937*`)
  - `std::subtract_with_carry_engine` (includes `std::ranlux*`)
- Random number distributions:
  Work "on top" of an RNG and allow to randomly generate numbers following a given distribution (uniform, normal, etc.).
- More things, [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Also recall that we have three main implementations of the C++ library (amongst others):

- MSVC’s MS STL
- gcc’s libstdc++
- clang’s libc++

A first aspect of the question is whether the behavior of the Random Number Generator (RNG) may change through time:

- The behavior of the the 3 RNGs is strictly defined in the C++ standard. In the case of the `std::mt19937` RNG, [it requires the 10,000th iteration of a default-constructed `std::mt19937` to produce a given value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine#Notes). In practice, it means we can assume that for a given seed, the sequence of number generated should be the same now and forever, for any implementation compliant to the standard.
- However, in the case of distributions, the C++ standard does not guarantee that a particular sequence of numbers will be generated, it only has to comply with the shape of the distribution. In particular, the sequence of number will change between implementations, and for a given implementation, it can change in time ie across versions. This change in behavior is documented in several other answers, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032845) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506550/consistent-random-number-generation-accross-platforms-with-boostrandom).

As a consequence:

- It is safe to write code assuming that the behavior of `std::mt19937` or any of the other two RNG families will be unchanged in time.
- On the other hand, code written based on distributions are likely to see their behavior altered in the future, as noted in the question.

It happened to me once to be writing unit tests whose code under test was calling internally `std::uniform_int_distribution<>()`. At some point of time those tests started failing, but rolling back from Visual Studio 2022 v17.7.4 to Visual Studio 2022 v17.4.2 made the tests pass again. Hence it appears that the implementation of `std::uniform_int_distribution<>()` changed in Visual Studio 2022 around version 17.5~17.6, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76596665/3492512) and [there](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3541). For instructions on how to rollback Visual Studio, see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studio-rollback/).

## The core question

How can I use the distributions, despite the risk that the sequence of numbers outputted might change?
Yes, but consider the following precautions:

- One could prefer using Boost’s implementations of the distributions in the [boost::random library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) instead of a standard library implementation. When developing cross-platform software, it has the advantage of being the same implementation independently of the platform, as noted by Sedenion.
- One could write a unit test that assesses that the sequence of numbers generated by the distributions remains unchanged eg using the already implemented [`operator<<()` for `std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/operator_ltltgtgt). In the contrary, such test(s) would act as an early alert indicating that other parts of the code may start behaving differently due to changes in implementation of the distribution, not the code itself.
- Once it is detected that the sequence of numbers issued by the distribution changed, some code testing could be performed to double check that the change in distribution does not alter significantly or negatively the expected behavior of the code, until next change in the distribution’s implementation…

Alternative solutions:

- Write our own distributions based on the C++ standard RNGs, this way it is easier to guarantee that their behavior does not change in time. (Note: it is also easy to implement them incorrectly…)
- If you do not require the random sequence to be different from a run to the next, then you could generate a static sequence of numbers from a distribution, store it eg in a header and use it ad aeternam. (Peter - Reinstante Monica)