# Random integer generation performance optimization

Tags: python, random

I am looking to generate random integers on the interval [0, n) as fast as possible:

```
from random import Random

rand = Random(123)

def rand_func(max: int, random: Random):
    return int(random.random() * max)

for a in range(10_000_000):                 # perf_counter 9.7s
    ax = rand_func(456, rand)

for b in range(10_000_000):                 # perf_counter 3.9s
    bx = int(rand.random() * 456)
```

My experience in other languages leaves me surprised at how expensive this function call seems to be.

Is there a method, pattern or decorator I could use to further optimize speed while keeping the code simple and usable?

I've looked at some other less simple solutions. numpy `random.integers` is very fast at returning a large array of results, but consuming the results becomes more complex and less ideal.

(Of note I'm aware of the bias in the random integer sampling method above but it is acceptable for my requirements).

Comment: I think you will just have to go down the numpy route if you want the speed.

Comment: @MattPitkin I guess my follow up question would then be is there some performant and simple pattern I can use to consume the numpy outputs? Using the output arrays raw is fast, but relatively less simple and not very re-usable. Wrapping them in more usable stuff seems to end me back at the starting point of slow code.

Comment: I suppose that really depends what you want to do with the outputs. Ideally you'd just leave things in numpy arrays and use numpy for any numerical stuff. You can just convert the numpy array back to a list using the [`.tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method if you want. If I time `[int(rand.random() * 456) for _ in range(10_000_000)]` it takes ~1.27 s, whereas timing the core of `import numpy as np; nprand = np.random.default_rng(); nprand.integers(low=0, high=456, size=10_000_000).tolist()` only takes 0.255 s.

Comment: Another option would be to use [pypy](https://www.pypy.org/) rather than standard cpython. In pypy, if I time `[int(rand.random() * 456) for _ in range(10_000_000)]` (after running it once, so that it does an initial compilation) it runs in 0.336 s. Still not as fast as numpy in cpython, but...

Comment: I’m finding your subject line to be misleading. Your code doesn’t contrast different ways of generating random integers, it’s looking at the overhead of wrapping the task in a function. Additionally, you should be using `randint` or `randrange`, which jump through hoops to guarantee a uniform distribution. Multiplying `rand` by a constant and truncating to integer is subtly non-uniform.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits/62920514

Answer (score 0):

Best algorithm as of now seems to be one of Daniel Lemire, https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10941. It was adopted in Go, and in GCC libstdc++ and recently by Microsoft MSVC++. Check [std::uniform_int_distribution changed in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76596665/stduniform-int-distribution-changed-in-visual-studio-2022-version-17-6#comment135057223_76596665) for details.