# Is it safe to use std::mt19937 (with fixed seed) within unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, random-seed

I had written a unit test of a function that requires a Random Number Generator (RNG). The implementation of the *tested function* starts with the following lines:

```
const int nSeed = 0;
std::mt19937 randNbGen(nSeed);
```

and the randNbGen object is later used within that same function to perform calculations that eventually yield its return value.

By seeding the RNG, it generates the same sequence of numbers from a run to the next, which I need for the unit test to be consistent. Also, I assumed that by using an RNG from the [std library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) ([std::mt19937](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) in my case) I was guaranteed that the sequence of numbers generated wouldn’t be changing in the future.

**However:** 6 months later (ie now) the test fails. I checked out a previous commit that used to pass the test, now it fails the test with the same function output as it currently does. I also note that randNbGen generates the same sequence of numbers in both commits.

Is it indeed possible that the RNG (implementation) changed? Or do I must have skrewed up somewhere?
What is the recommended way to handle this situation?
Bonus question: is the RNG's behavior constant accross platforms?

PS: I'm using MSVC on Windows (Visual Studio 2022)

Comment: The generator `std::mt19937` cites a specific version of Mersenne Twister by name : 32-bit Mersenne Twister by Matsumoto and Nishimura, 1998 It seems unlikely to me that they could ever meaningfully change it.

Comment: It is not unsafe but it will just generate the same sequence of random numbers over and over again assuming you don't use distributions (distrubutions add their own state to the generated output and this is allowed to change)).  I think the failiing tests would worry me more ... if I would use a random generator I would expect all my tests to keep succeeding no matter the input. (Lookup Fuzzing)

Comment: What does _"the test fails"_ mean ? What makes you think the issue comes from the RNG ? Maybe your code has an issue elsewhere, or has undefined behaviour, or ... we can't know without knowing which code fails, what you expected, and what you got instead.

Comment: Ok, to give a bit of context, the tested function performs a ransac linear regression ie given a set of points it randomly selects some points and use them to perform a linear regression.

Comment: Hence, if different points are chosen, I might still get a line that have similar but not identical characteristics (eg slope) then when the test was written.

Comment: Hence, the tested function behaves well, but the test fails because it was expecting a slightly different value than what it got.

Comment: Whether a function ends without error (and spits out a plausible result) doesn't prove that it worked nor that it's well-formed. Especially with undefined behaviour, your program may appear to work and someday, not. You should check the generated values with the same seed, I bet they remained the same, meaning the error is in your function. I would debug the function instead of blindly assuming it's right (very often the error is in the part we never questioned)

Comment: @Fareanor what makes me think that it might be the RNG, is that going back to the original commit in which the test was written, I get the same output as currently, and hence the test fails, whereas it did not use to. But as the same time, as françoisAndrieux noted, it seems unlikely that std:mt19937 changed, hence my confusion… Undefined behavior could be a track indeed, as you say…

Comment: @GaelLorieul What do you test ? This is the real question here. What you describe seems to prove the opposite of your claim, if the results remains the same. Once again, what does _"the test fails"_ mean ? What do you test ? It will lead you to what is wrong in your code. We can't help much because you didn't provide enough information.

Comment: @Fareanor I don't think it's necessary to know about their tests. The question is pretty self-contained, how stable is `std::mt19937` with regards to standard library versions?.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Maybe I missed something but, if the output are the same, and if the generated number from the RNG are the same, but the test results changed, for me, we need to know what is tested exactly to see why it failed. Either the code, or the test, or both are wrong. I don't even see how `std::mt19937` is related in any way to this issue (it did generate the same numbers with the same seed all the time so it's stable).

Comment: Note that the function output and RNG sequence is the same when comparing commits *now*, but I have no way to check whether the RNG sequence and function output used to be different 6 months ago. However, since the test passed 6 months ago and fails now, the function output must have been different.

Comment: @GaelLorieul You could add an earlier test to validate the initial sequence (or internal state with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/operator_ltltgtgt) of your random number generator to confirm that it doesn't change.

Comment: @Fareanor what the test assessses is the value of the a, b, c coefficients of the parametrization (a*x + b*y - c = 0) of the Ransac line. Test gets a = 8.666606, whereas it expects a = 8.751696. ie, not a world apart. As Pepijn mentioned, I could be testing if the function manages to find a reasonable line, which might be enough to assess that the function does a good job. In contrast, I have a very low tolerance on the line coefficients because I also want to assess that the code keeps behaving (almost) exactly the same.

Comment: One troubling fact that I have not mentioned so far, is that another test (tested and testing code written by someone else, so I am not very familiar with it) also happens to fail, and it happens to use RNGs as well… The ransac function that I am testing and the other failing code are not dependent one on the other.

Comment: But as François mentioned, the heart of my question is not so much to fix my problem, but whether I can safely assume that std::mt19937 always behaves and will keep behaving the same. So far, from what I read, this appears to be a reasonable assumption…

Comment: The random number generators in the standard library use fully specified algorithms (including a requirement for the 1000th value generated, which is handy when implementing them). If your tests are failing now, it's not the fault of the RNG.

Comment: Note that the other parts of the random library are less tightly specified, if you're using distributions for example they could well change with a new standard library version

Comment: If you use `std::uniform_real_distribution` or any other distribution, that is likely a problem. They are not guaranteed to follow any particular algorithm and do not need to be consistent across versions. Otherwise, and assuming no outright UB, I would look at the floating point math used in the test case. There is quite a bit of behavior variance that a compiler can choose from and that may vary between versions.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Another note: if you log the random sequence and size of the sequence is constant, generate and save the sequence once, and use it everywhere.

Comment: I see that I use `std::uniform_int_distribution<>` internally. From what Pepijn, Alan and user wrote, the behavior of std::mt19937 is constant across versions and implementations of the standard library, but the behavior of the distribution is not. So that must be it! The following post gives some recommendation on how to handle that situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032845/3492512 TL;DR: prefer boost.random to have same behavior across platforms and run checks whenever updating the boost version.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) One of you guys is probably more deserving to be the author of the answer, otherwise I’d add it myself.

Comment: Example of change of distribution with change of VisualStudio version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76596665/stduniform-int-distribution-changed-in-visual-studio-2022-version-17-6

Comment: I confirm that rolling back from Visual Studio 2022 v17.7.4 to Visual Studio 2022 v17.4.2 made the tests pass. Apparently they changed the implementation of std::uniform_int_distribution<> in Visual Studio 2022 around version 17.5~17.6 https://stackoverflow.com/q/76596665/3492512 https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a summary of multiple contributions from various users that you will find in the comments of the original question: thanks to all who helped!

Recall that the [C++ standard offers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

- Three main Random Number Generators (RNGs):
  Generate sequences of (pseudo-)random numbers.

  - `std::linear_congruential_engine` (includes `std::minstd*`)
  - `std::mersenne_twister_engine` (includes `std::mt19937*`)
  - `std::subtract_with_carry_engine` (includes `std::ranlux*`)
- Random number distributions:
  Work "on top" of an RNG and allow to randomly generate numbers following a given distribution (uniform, normal, etc.).
- More things, [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Also recall that we have three main implementations of the C++ library (amongst others):

- MSVC’s MS STL
- gcc’s libstdc++
- clang’s libc++

A first aspect of the question is whether the behavior of the Random Number Generator (RNG) may change through time:

- The behavior of the the 3 RNGs is strictly defined in the C++ standard. In the case of the `std::mt19937` RNG, [it requires the 10,000th iteration of a default-constructed `std::mt19937` to produce a given value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine#Notes) (Pete Becker). In practice, it means we can assume that for a given seed, the sequence of number generated should be the same now and forever, for any implementation compliant to the standard.
- However, in the case of distributions, the C++ standard does not guarantee that a particular sequence of numbers will be generated, it only has to comply with the shape of the distribution. In particular, the sequence of number will change between implementations, and for a given implementation, it can change in time ie across versions (Alan Birtles, user17732522). This change in behavior is documented in several other answers, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032845) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506550/consistent-random-number-generation-accross-platforms-with-boostrandom).

As a consequence:

- It is safe to write unit tests assuming that the behavior of `std::mt19937` or any of the other two RNG families will be unchanged in time.
- On the other hand, unit tests written based on distributions are likely to be failing in the future.

In my particular case, even though I thought I was using `std::mt19937` directly, it turned out that I was actually using `std::uniform_int_distribution<>`. That is why unit tests that used to pass were now failing. Actually, rolling back from Visual Studio 2022 v17.7.4 to Visual Studio 2022 v17.4.2 made the tests pass. Hence it appears that the implementation of `std::uniform_int_distribution<>` changed in Visual Studio 2022 around version 17.5~17.6, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76596665/3492512) and [there](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3541). For instructions on how to rollback Visual Studio, see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studio-rollback/).

Can I use the distributions within unit tests, despite the risk that the sequence of numbers outputted might change?
Yes, but consider the following precautions:

- One could prefer using Boost’s implementations of the distributions in the [boost::random library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) instead of a standard library implementation. When developing cross-platform software, it has the advantage of being the same implementation independently of the platform.
- One could write a test that assesses that the sequence of numbers generated by the distributions remains unchanged eg using the already implemented [`operator<<()` for `std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/operator_ltltgtgt) (François Andrieux). In the contrary, such test(s) would act as an early alert indicating that the other failing unit tests are due to changes in implementation of the distribution, not the code itself.
- Once it is detected that the sequence of number issued by the distribution changed, alter the expected values of the unit tests accordingly, until next change in the distribution’s implementation…

Alternative solutions:

- One could write tests that run several times and test the distribution of the randomly obtained outputs eg their mean and/or standard deviation. (Note: not sure how convenient that would be, because that might slow down the test considerably, which is not desirable.)
- Write our own distributions based on the C++ standard RNGs, this way it is easier to guarantee that their behavior does not change in time (Red.Wave) . (Note: it is also easy to implement them incorrectly…)
- If you do not require the random sequence to be different from a run to the next, then you could generate a static sequence of numbers from a distribution, store it eg in a header and use it ad aeternam. (Peter - Reinstante Monica)

Comment: Perhaps the best solution is to generate a few GB or TB of pseudo random numbers with a given generator and use those from now on (after all, you seem to need a known sequence, so why not use one ;-) ).

Comment: Added to the list of alternative solutions! 

Comment: nice.... even though it has nothing to do with a specific seed.

Comment: This answer is exemplary, but the questions looks like a duplicate of [deterministic alternative to std::uniform_XXX_distribution with mt19937?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74031210/5740428). I think you should add it to the linked Q&A too.

Comment: @JanSchultke Done! However, it felt to me that the "unit test" application gave a different twist to the question, despite the obvious similarity between both questions. In practice, I was not able to adapt the answer without stripping some parts of it that were relevant to my "duplicate" question due to the unit test application, but not so much to the "original" question. Also, some parts of the adapted question feel clunky, for example "Once it is detected […], some code testing could be performed […] until next change in the distribution’s implementation…" part, which sounds impractical.